# Does my Xcode project broken

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-project

My Xcode iOS project is kind of broken I think.When I create a new file in my group,the file's location is somewhat different from other Xcode iOS project.For example,when I create a Cocoa Touch Class called `EEViewController`,you can find its location is too long in the `Identity and Type` of the `File inspector`.
[image]

But when I right click the file and click `Show In Finder`,drag the file to the desktop and drag it back the its original group.The location's patch seems to be okay.(It can finally be referenced in Storyboard custom class)
[image]

I think it is has something to do with my Xcode configuration,but I just can't figured it out.Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my understanding, `../../../benson/OneHome/OneHome/EEViewController.swift` is relatively the same as just `EEViewController.swift` in your case as it's based on the location related to the group.

`../` means go up 1 level in the path, up 3 level then dive in 3 makes it the same path.

I think the issue here is the case of your home dir. In the second screenshot it shows "**B**enson" and the first shows "**b**enson". OS X is a case sensitive file system, that might be a problem for Xcode.

Comment: That's the issue! I have move my Xcode project out of the `benson` folder,and everything is going back normal.